# C-Segmentation fault (core dumped) error in linux

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct fileIndex{
    char name;
    int key;
} index1;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int i;
    FILE *pFile;

    pFile= fopen("cat/home/sysadmin/deneme.txt","r");



    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        printf("%c",fgetc(pFile));
    }
    fclose(pFile);

}
```

When I want to run my program, it gives that error. I looked so long for a wrong line in code, but I didn't find any. Can you help me ?

Comment: Please indent your code. And please check at least the return values from error prone functions such as `fopen`.

Comment: It seems to me like you want the [`popen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) function, not `fopen`. And then add a space between the command (`cat`) and its argument.

Comment: Are you sure this path - `cat/home/sysadmin/deneme.txt` is correct? I guess you mean `/home/sysadmin/deneme.txt`.

Answer (score 3):

If the file failed to open, that will make `pFile` equal `NULL`, which can easily cause `fgetc()` to segfault.

You must check for this before trying to read from the file:

```
if (pfile == NULL)
{
  perror("Failed to open file");
  exit(1);
}
```

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Ooh, overkill! Sure, why not: :)

Answer (score 1):

change your code as

```
int i;
FILE *pFile;

pFile= fopen("cat/home/sysadmin/deneme.txt","r");

if(!pFile)
  return;
```

Also.. looks like you file path is misplaced... are your meant t ouse `/cat/home/sysadmin/deneme.txt`

Is `cat` your current directory or part of absolute path